# Why c_str() doesn't output an address when it returns a const pointer value

Tags: c++

I'm studying pointer and got confused with c_str() function.

The description says it returns a constant Null terminated pointer to the character array and when i try to print the variable, it doesn't print the address of it.

```
int main() {
    string a = "hello";
    const char* b = a.c_str();
    cout << b << endl; //hello
}
```

I expected the output to be the address of b but instead it prints "hello".

Can someone explain why?

Comment: `char*` is an exception in the world of pointers

Answer (score 7):

There's an [overload of `operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) for `std::ostream` and `const char*`, that will print the string rather than the pointer value (address).

You can cast to `const void*` to invoke the overload that prints the address.

```
cout << static_cast<const void*>(b);
```